# Select and Insert query asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm using asp.net form, I have a select query and insert into query but however if I get the select error message; "Invalid Barcode"; it is still inserting into the database. I'm not sure how to just incorporate everything; When the user gets the error message; it should not be inserted but if it is successful it gives them a successful message.

```
if (barcode.StartsWith("B"))
        {
            string Data = " select boxLocation from Box where boxNo= " + barcode.TrimStart('B') + "";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {

            lblResult.Text = dr[0].ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = barcode + " does not exist!!";

        }
    }
if (barcode.StartsWith("B"))
    {
        command.CommandText = "insert into Crate_Box (crate_box_no,Current_Location,Previous_Location, Username,Date,status,codeType)values (@crate_box_no,@Current_Location,@Previous_Location, @Username,@Date,@status,@codeType) ";

        command.Parameters.Add("@crate_box_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = barcode.TrimStart('B');
        command.Parameters.Add("@Current_Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = location;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Previous_Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lblResult.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = date;
        command.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = actType;
        command.Parameters.Add("@codeType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Box";
    }
```

Comment: Your if conditions are the same....

Comment: @IrishChieftain; yeah but I just want to put insert into in that if statement; to eliminate having the same if statement

Comment: Use an if/else?

Comment: @IrishChieftain; I can't use if else because I want both those queries? I don't see how if/else would work

Comment: @IrishChieftain can the insert into and select be placed in one if statement

Comment: Sure, I see no reason why not.However, if you want to get more answers I suggest you update your question with a better description of what it is your app does. Right now it's a guessing game.

Comment: @IrishChieftain can you give me a little snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try the following structure:

```
    if (barcode.StartsWith("B"))
    {
        try
        {
            // SELECT operation
            // INSERT operation
        }
        catch
        {
            lblError.Text = barcode + " does not exist!!";
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close DB connections and readers
        }
    }
```

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            { do I remove that section

Comment: I gave you the structure. You need to add the code for the read and the insert in the try block. Am updating answer to include a finally block to release your resources.